# Looking for all-encompassing website to download standards (UL, NEC, ISO, etc)

Tags: industrial, documentation

TLDR : Frustrated with the way standards are handled in my industry bc they are important, looking for one website that does it all.

I am a controls engineer and have been in this industry for about 7 years now. One of my struggles is finding a website that is a one stop shop for all standards for my industry that do not charge an arm and a leg for one edition. One of my frustrations is something like UL508a costs about $500, but will reference other UL standards within, which also happen to cost $500 each. I want something that is subscription based for individuals, because I have also found it not popular for companies to pay for subscriptions to allow employees to download things at will.

I briefly worked for a robotics company and an integrator, and have seen many many references to all sorts of safety standards for robots, hazardous locations like paint booths (class 1 div 1 etc), and your typical UL and NEC standards for panels that also have many references to even things like fuse classifications (e.g. UL248-8 class J having its very own document)

I am not interested in using google every time I need to look something up and clicking through a 100 websites only to find a random PDF someone uploaded 10 years ago.

Has anyone discovered a solution to this, or am I just whining?

Comment: You also seek the holy grail?

Comment: Running a standards organization costs money, and one source of revenue is to charge for standards documents. Other models include membership fees (e.g. Bluetooth SIG), government grants, and open volunteer-based initiatives. UL happens to be the first revenue model.

Comment: And maybe this should just be a thought exercise, but now try doing it for a day without google.  Just phone, physical copy and snail mail lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IHS offers such a subscription service: https://global.ihs.com/

Be prepared to shell out in the 5 figures annually, though. It’s simply the cost of doing business.

Comment: most universities have subscriptions (At least in Australia) to the standards. Sign up for short courses so you can access their libraries.